# How to make a each word in a string starts with uppercase letter in WP7 Silverlight?

Tags: string, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've tried some codes like

```
string s = "this is example";
txt1TextBlock.Text = Thread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s);
```

But it seems that WP7 Silverlight it is different..

is there any way to do that?

thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following,

```
String s = "this is example";
string result = "";
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
for (int i = 0, l = words.Length; i < l; ++i)
{
     result = result + words[i][0].ToString().ToUpper() + words[i].Substring(1) + " ";
}
MessageBox.Show("Old Value: "+s+" New Value: "+result);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I recommend `words[i].Substring(1).ToLower()` as we don't guarantee that the original sentence is written in a lower case.

Answer (score 0):

As we don't have Split method in String class for Silverlight windows phone.. You should use the basic string functions like SubString(),Append(), Replace(),ToUpper() and ToLower()..

Please refer the following tutorial..

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/stephenarmbrust/FunctiontoChangeaBlockofTextofTitleCase11232005231948PM/FunctiontoChangeaBlockofTextofTitleCase.aspx